# Interference and absortion filters

Tags: spectrophotometry

I am learning a bit about Uv-vis spectroscopy filters. As far as I know there are two commonly used: interference and absotion filters.
The first one works with the interference of light principle and the second is a glass with some pigments which absorbs light (of some specific frequency).

**Question**

Have you got any idea if there is any further classification of absortion filters? Any help will be greatly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There are a great many of each type of these filters.

[Interference filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_filter) are optimized for different wavelengths, different bandwidths, transmission vs. reflection etc. by controlling the materials and the thicknesses of the layers. A commercial supplier, [Edmund Optics, shows how to specify and order filters](https://www.edmundoptics.com/resources/application-notes/optics/optical-filters/).

In a similar manner, [absorptive filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_filter#Absorptive) depend on the chemicals used to make them. [For example, a solution of $\ce{CuSO4}$, copper sulfate, in water removes wavelengths between ~600-750 nm, but letting blue light through.](http://pubs.rsc.org/services/images/RSCpubs.ePlatform.Service.FreeContent.ImageService.svc/ImageService/Articleimage/2013/CE/c3ce40974k/c3ce40974k-f8.gif).

Comment: Possibly I haven't been clear enough. I wonder if there is any further classification of absortion filters...Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: Sure: you could classify them any number of ways: Solid, liquid or gaseous? Absorption due to chemical formula or due to colloidal properties (e.g. CuSO4 blue vs. colloidal-gold-in-glass red)? Solid filters could be subdivided into single vs. multilayer, glass vs. plastic... What is the point of your question? Classification is arbitrary.